# Best practice for resetting scroll position between pages?

Tags: polymer, dart-polymer

So even the Polymer website has this issue. This is an SPA-world problem.

Repro: Go to http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html, click on e.g. core-ajax on the left and scroll down to the middle, then goto core-xhr. Note the scroll position.

What are some best practices considering that I a) want to avoid behavior like the above, but also b) want to preserve the scroll position for when I use the back arrow to goto a page I've already been? It'd be nice if core-pages had support built in.

Comment: This problem gets even more annoying if you have some animations in your app, e.g. a hero transition. Imagine for example a long list of cards and each card is animated into a title box at the top of the new page. If the list is scrolled down, then the hero element transitions to a position way above the visible screen and vanishes, which is very confusing for the user. So during a page transition the scroll position should be reset to the top, but also the animations need to be calculated between the right locations.

Comment: You are both right. I will endeavor to communicate this to the team, but maybe you could put this in an email to `polymer-dev@googlegroups.com` or post a ticket to [core-pages issue tracker](https://github.com/polymer/core-pages/issues).

Comment: @ScottMiles, done and done. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/polymer-dev/tDetYDnxG48

Comment: Is there a workaround yet? I can't make it work as expected. Hero transition with core-animated-pages is unusable.

Comment: I'm currently running into this issue as well.

Answer (score 3):

This might work as a workaround. You can use the **fire** event in polymer, once something fire the event you **listen** to the call and force the page to **scroll to top**. At least this solved my problem with *core-animated-pages* transition: *slide-from-right*.

**Polymer**

`this.fire('scroll-top')`

**Index.html**

```
document.addEventListener('scroll-top', function(){
    // Access the main core-header-panel 
    var scaffold = document.querySelector('core-scaffold');
    var scrollArea = scaffold.shadowRoot.querySelector('core-header-panel');
    scrollArea.scroller.scrollTop = 0; // Scroll to top
    }
)
```

Answer (score -1):

**update 01/01/2018**

Polymer now has a nice element for this:

[iron-scroll-threshold](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/iron-scroll-threshold)